# Get SVG from react-icons components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, paperjs

I need to get the svg element from a react-icon component to render the image using a different Javascript library.

I'm using [paperjs](https://paperjs.org) as the drawing engine for this demo I'm working on, for the UI I use **react-icons** and **react-bootstrap**. Now paperjs allows to [importSVG](http://paperjs.org/reference/shape/#importsvg-svg) images, so I try the following:

```js
import { MdMemory } from "react-icons/md";

const addDevice = () => {
  const svgGroup = Paper.project.importSVG(<MdMemory />);
  svgGroup.position = pointA.clone();
}
```

But when I do so I get the following error: `Error: Unsupported SVG source: [object Object]`

When I inspect the other place where I use `<MdMemory />` I get an `svg` element, so I wonder if what I'm trying to achieve is possible as I don't want to load duplicated assets.

**UPDATE**

After spending a bit more time, I came up with the following:

```js
console.log(MdMemory().props.children[0].props.d);
const svgGroup = Paper.project.importSVG(`<svg><path d=${MdMemory().props.children[0].props.d}></path></svg>`);
```

Where `MdMemory().props.children[0].props.d` is the actual svg path, but I'm still unable to render anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! to achieve this you will need to

1. Extract the path element like so `MdMemory().props.children[0].props.d`
2. Create an `svg` string like `const svg = "..."`

```js
const addDevice = () => {
  const svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"> <path d="${MdMemory().props.children[0].props.d}"></path></svg>`;
  const svgGroup = Paper.project.importSVG(svg);
  svgGroup.fillColor = 'black';
  svgGroup.position = pointA.clone();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked better for me:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<MdMemory/>)
```

Answer (score -1):

I just searched for the icon on React Icons and inspected that icon through console, and then I copied and pasted it:

- Browser

  [image: browser]
- Copying

  [image: copying]
- Paste

  [image: pasting]